# How to import data using Mojo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mojolang

I am trying to import a simple csv file into Modular's programming language Mojo, but can not find any documented methods to for importing / exporting data. The documentation is still light but this is a basic need.

I read through the documentation, got onto the JupyterLab they have hosted, and googled the issues but am still left without knowing. Are we just supposed to import pandas and use it that way? If so, why am I using Mojo at all?

Comment: Maybe the current solution is to use Python methods... This language currently gives me the impression that I can run the same code on it, but it performs better than Python